# splitting a too large method in android

Tags: android, methods

I am a beginner and I am creating an android app in java with android studio. it is a ListView with more than 2000 items. When the user clicks on an item, he will be taken to a certain map location. when I run the app, it says code is too large because of the large method !!! I have read almost every post about this subject and they all suggest that I should split the method into smaller methods, or add another class or (.file) to my recourses. So I know my problem is writing too many (if statement) lines inside my method because I am a beginner and I did them manually. Could you Please show me a detailed step by step guide to solve "code is too large".
Thanks a lot

```
 
    package com.example.myapplicationsecond;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.myapplicationsecond.R;

public class MainActivity9 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    String[] name = {

            "first location ",
            "second location",
            "third location",
            "fourth location",
            "fifth location",
            "sixth location",
until 2000th location

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main9);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.abs_layout, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);

    TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    Title.setText("search here");

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view,params);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //show custom title
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the default title


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("search here");


    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            String clickedText = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);

            int positionInArray = java.util.Arrays.asList(name).indexOf(clickedText);


            if(positionInArray==0){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr= 21.422503, 39.826179"));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
            if(positionInArray==1){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr= 24.468333, 39.610833"));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            if(positionInArray==2){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr= N 26 23.026 E 44 59.378"));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
            if(positionInArray==3){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr= 26.403737, 44.912791"));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
            if(positionInArray==4){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr= N 26 36.698 E 47 34.159"));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
            if(positionInArray==5){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr= N 26 05.760 E 46 29.135"));
                startActivity(intent);

until 2000th line
```

Comment: You should not be creating an if statement with over a thousand cases. You need to make your code dynamic, where are you getting your google map links from? Are they stored somewhere?

Comment: Keep a `HashMap<Integer,String>` to get the URL .

Comment: CodeGorilla: I have them in a table in MS word to make them easy for copy and paste. ADM: Thanks, but please I need steps because I am a beginner.

Comment: For saving such an amount of data you should be using a Persistent Storage .. a database or a File .. Using a file is easy since you only have to read it all at once.  Save data in file a CSV or maybe a Json. then read it in a Map .. Answering this will be a lot so u need search for each part .. Like how to read file from assets and other stuff .

Comment: Did you really type out all the words for the ordinal numbers up to 2000? Such as `"one thousand nine hundred seventy-fifth location"`? And are you open to using Kotlin? The reason I ask is that reading these items from a text or CSV file into your program would be easier in Kotlin than in Java. One general tip about beginning programming--don't forget you are a programmer. You should not be copy-pasting from a large table. As a programmer, you can command computers to do tedious work on your behalf.

Comment: Tenfour04: Thanks, actually I can't switch to Kotlin now. For the 2000 lines, I wrote them manually by using macros. Anyway, I hope someone may help me with my issue.

Comment: Thanks ADM, could you please explain more? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you're a beginner it's understandable that this is all very overwhelming so  here's a few pointers to help you along. This is not a complete solution nor is it what would be widely considered to be best practice but it will help move you forwards from where you are. I hope you take something from it.

Firstly create a class to represent objects that hold information about your locations. i.e their names and latLon.

```
class Location {
    private String name;
    private String latLon;

    public Location(String name, String latLon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latLon = latLon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLatLon() {
        return latLon;
    }
}
```

You can then replace your `name` array with an array of these items like so

```
Location[] locations = {
        new Location("first location", "24.468333, 39.610833"),
        new Location("second location", "24.468333, 39.610833"),
        new Location("third location", "24.468333, 39.610833"),
        new Location("fourth location", "24.468333, 39.610833")
        // and so on
};
```

Now you need a way of extracting a list of the location names to display in your `ListView` . For that you can use the below function

```
private List<String> getNamesFromLocations(Location[] locations) {
    // creates a new ArrayList to hold the names of locations
    ArrayList<String> locationNames = new ArrayList<>();
    // this iterates through the array one item at a time
    for (Location location : locations) {
        // get the location name and add it to the new list defined in this function
        locationNames.add(location.getName());
    }
    // return the location names
    return locationNames;
}
```

You can now use this function to create your list of location names and use it to initialise the `ArrayAdapter`

```
List<String> names = getNamesFromLocations(locations);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

In the listView `onItemClick` function you can take the position of the item that was clicked and use that to grab the location at the same position in the `locations` array

```
Location location = locations[position];
String latLon = location.getLatLon();
```

Then you can make the code that creates your Intent cleaner by combining this String (which is the same in each of your if statements) `"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr = "` with the latLon specific to you location

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr&daddr = " + latLon));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried doing what you told me carefully guys even following Ivan's steps but no luck. The code generated more errors. I am extremely thankful guys and appreciate if someone makes it easier for me because I am really stuck with this error for almost two months.

Comment: even though I still didn't solve my problem, I just want to thank Ivan Wooll for his effort and the others.